# User-friendly elapsed time / date difference in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm looking for a ready-to-use solution to the problem of presenting the user with the time elapsed between two dates, like in "*1 year, 3 months and 17 days ago*".

Is there any library that provides this functionality?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use NSDate, NSDateComponents, NSCalendar, the date [programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/DatesAndTimes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000039i) gives a pretty thorough explanation.

Comment: Thanks, the method "components:fromDate:toDate:options:" from NSDateComponents does exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still looking for a "ready to use solution", checkout: https://github.com/MatthewYork/DateTools#time-ago